# Three.js Points Rotation

Tags: javascript, d3.js, three.js, rotation

I'm working on a particle system project. I want to add a little delay to my Points Object rotation in three.js. I'm currently using D3.js linear scale which gives 1:1 rotation. For example, if you quickly move your cursor all the way to right, my Points Object will match your cursor movement speed. What I want is to ease in the rotation so the rotation would finish ~1sec after you move your cursor all the way to the right. Here is my current code.

```
var rotYScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, window.innerWidth]).range([25,-25]);
var rotXScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, window.innerHeight]).range([15,-15]);
d3.select("body").on("mousemove", function() { 
  particleSystem.rotation.y = rotYScale(d3.mouse(this)[0]) * Math.PI / 180;
  particleSystem.rotation.x = rotXScale(d3.mouse(this)[1]) * Math.PI / 180; 
});`
```

Comment: here is an example of the delayed rotation
http://www.deutser.com/

Comment: have you got a working example of what you have so far ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by using Tween.js. This is the code I added.

```
var tween = new TWEEN.Tween(particleSystem.rotation).to({ x: scaledX, y: scaledY, z: 0})
tween.easing( TWEEN.Easing.Quadratic.Out)
tween.start();
```